# Can someone give an example method

Tags: java

I am new to java and am just practicing. I have this question and wondering if anyone can give me an example for this please.

Method that accepts a string parameter and returns a value that is the result of using string and/or character processing

Comment: This is trivial to figure out on your own. Just start coding.

Comment: @Jabber - Please don't look at answers. I'm saying this for your own benefit. You are learning java right, so please try to create that method. First find how to create a method. Then find how to pass an argument to method. Then find how to return value from a method etc... Trust me... This will be really useful for you.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages

Comment: @Jabber Please do not accept and unaccept answers unless there is a very good reason to do so. You should not accept an answer unless it very specifically answers your question or solves your problem.

Comment: There are many good examples of this on the web. If you find a good one and run it and you get a specific error or problem, post the details on this site and you will find many willing to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Just an example of a method that returns the first char of the string:

```
char getFirstChar (String s) {
    return s.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this would work... as you can't do `return s[0];`

Comment: This is invalid Java code and produces the error message `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String`. Use `s.charAt(0)` instead.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I confused it with C# code. My fault.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually simple -

inside main method do:

```
public String returnString(String myString){
    String newString = new StringBuilder("text").append(myString).toString();
    return newString;
}

System.out.println(returnString("string"));
```

- First you will declare a method called returnString.
- Second you will create an object that puts two strings together.
- Third you return the processing of this string concatenation.
- Fourth call the method you've just created to print the text you passed as argument to the method processed.

I haven't tested this, but it should work!

Comment: Why would you use a StringBuilder for something so trivial? Be sure to use proper coding styles/formatting.

Comment: The intention is to show the string and/or character processing. Instead of creating a method to do this processing, I used one object already built that will do processing ...